# React rendering problem in input box after fetching data in useEffect(). the state changed but textbox value not changing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rendering, use-effect

I am new in react but not in programming. And learning in more than 6 months. It was quite simple to render state value in dom but now I feel very difficult to render state value in input textbox. I have to update value from a form, that need to retrieve value and show in textbox. But I could not. I used mongodb, express, nodejs in backend. For state management used redux toolkit. I investigate developer tools, its OK. Here is my component where I wanted to render-

---

```
const UpdateCategory = () => {
  const {id}=useParams();  
  const dispatch=useDispatch();
  const {category, success}=useSelector(state=>state.categoryDetails);
  const [catName,setCatName]=useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getCategoryDetails(id));
      //setCatName(category.name);
      let cName=category && category.name;
      if(cName){
        setCatName(cName);
      }

  }, [dispatch,id])
  return (
    <>   
        <label>{category && category.name}</label>
        <input type='text' value={catName} onChange={(e)=>setCatName(e.target.value)}/>
    </>
  )
}
export default UpdateCategory
```

and here is my redux toolkit action and slicers

---

```
export const getCategoryDetails=createAsyncThunk("categoryDetails/getCategoryDetails", async(id, thunkAPI)=>{
    try{        
        const {data}=await api.getCategoryDetailsApi(id);
        return data;
    }catch(error){
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
    }
})
const categoryDetailsSlice=createSlice({
    name:"categoryDetails",
    initialState:{
            category:{},
        },

    reducers:{
        //remove category details error
        removeCategoryLoadError:(state)=>{            
            state.error=null;
        },
       categoryFounded:(state)=>{
            //state.category=state.category;
            state.success=true;
        },                
    },
    extraReducers:{
        //CATEGORY DETAILS-------------
        [getCategoryDetails.pending]:(state,action)=>{
            state.success=false;
            state.loading=true;
            state.category=null;
        },
        [getCategoryDetails.fulfilled]:(state,action)=>{
            state.loading=false;
            state.category=action.payload.category;
            state.success=action.payload.success;
        },
        [getCategoryDetails.rejected]:(state,action)=>{
            state.loading=false;
            state.category=null;
            state.error=action.payload;
        },     
    }
});
export const {
    removeCategoryLoadError,
    categoryFounded,
} = categoryDetailsSlice.actions;

export default  categoryDetailsSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Don't add these messages like `I am learning react for months etc.` only talk about what you've tried and what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

So we can try something like this you had dispatch and dispatch is only created when this component mounts so having it as a dependancy wont help in this case we need to see when the store state updates

```
Please also console.log(the category.name) before the return statement of the JSX to see the results if the data is even getting updated if so then the category is updating and whenever the category updates we want to     

//this is to handle the action when component mounts
    useEffect(() => {
              dispatch(getCategoryDetails(id));
          }, [])

//this is to handle updating the local state when store state of category is updated
     useEffect(() => {
              if(category && category.name){
                setCatName(cName);
              }
            return () => {
            setCatName('')
            }
        
          }, [category, id])

// also why don't you rather do something like this instead of having it //update some local state cause that is a bit of a anti-pattern seen as you //already have the data if its getting updated correctly then you don't even need the useEffect to update the local state ?

<input type='text' value={category.name || ''} onChange={(e)=>setCatName(e.target.value)}/>

//finally what you could also have your store state as could have the //initial values
initialState:{
            category:{
               name: '',
            },
        },
```

Comment: Thanks'. The useEffect() hook should be used 2nd time. Thank's a lot.